# finding complex roots with an Argand diagram, with two variables

Tags: complex-numbers

Hello I am struggling to see how the equation
$$x^6 + \omega^6 = 0$$ is solved, there should be 6 pairs of roots right? I can solve $$x^6=1$$ and find the six roots fine with de moivres' and the proper multiples of \pi to find the 6 roots of x.

But with this equation it seems that for each pair the root pairing will cancel each other out. I suppose the equation implies that symmetry anyway because $$x^6 = -\omega^6$$ but that doesn't help me much.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure $\omega$ is meant to be an unknown? You can choose $\omega$ to be _whatever you want_ and then find six different matching $x$s by multiplying your $\omega$ by odd powers of $\frac12(\sqrt3+i)$. (Except for $\omega=0$, in which case all six solutions for $x$ are $0$ too).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes the question is exactly as written with no values given for either variable.

Comment: x @Joshua: Then, are you sure $\omega$ is meant to be an unknown, and _why_ are you sure of that? It sounds like you're saying that the problem statement gives you _no reason_ to assume that $\omega$ is not just a constant.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's a question about finding complex roots using an argand diagram... see the other answer which is closer to the solution.

To balance the equation there should be pairs of complex roots that balance each other, see this link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E6+%2B+w%5E6+%3D0

Comment: x @Joshua: Nothing about that appears to give you _any reason whatsoever_ for insisting that $\omega$ must be an unknown. DonAntonio's answer does not treat it like an unknown either. Neither does Wolfram Alpha treat the $w$ you write as an unknown -- it tells you (clumsily!) what the solutions for $x$ are _once you know $w$_!

Comment: If you were asked to solve $ax^2+bx+c=0$, would you also insist that $a$, $b$, $c$ are unknowns and expect to get a solution in the form of a set of quadruples $(a,b,c,x)$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but it seems in anycase the solution I am looking for is that wolphram one.

Comment: If you think Wolfram Alpha's solution _for just the single unknown $x$_ is what you're looking for, then I sincerely suggest you stop insisting that you want to treat $\omega$ as an unknown!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well what's the difference between something being a variable, and something being unknown? 

With the information given you just have to assume that the solution is in terms of either one of the variables, the solution could have been written in either $x$ or $\omega$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$z^6=-w^6\implies \left(\frac zw\right)^6=-1=e^{\pi i(1+2k)}$$

and now do as with "usual" roots of unity and at the end substitute $\;\cfrac zw\;$ .

Comment: This has put me in the right direction 
my solutions will be found from $$cos(\theta) + i sin (\theta) = -1 $$ can I just multiply my results by -1 to account for the RHS? 

Like I mentioned in my post I solved $$x^6 =1$$ in the same manner earlier.

Comment: I actually have seen the solution here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E6+%2B+w%5E6+%3D0 and I'm super close but how do I end up with that w^2 in the square roots in the numerators?

Comment: @Joshua the roots are

$$\frac zw=e^{\frac{\pi i}6(1+2k)}\;,\;\;k=0,1,2,...,5=\begin{cases}
e^{\pi i/6}=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\\
e^{\pi i/2}=i\\
e^{5\pi i/6}=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\\
e^{7\pi i/6}=-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\\
e^{3\pi i/2}=-i\\
e^{11\pi i/6}=\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\end{cases}$$As you can see, and as it is expectable with **even** roots, we have three pairs of (root, -root): the first and the fourth, the second and fifth, and the third and the sixth ones.

Comment: Yes thank you I arrived at that solution just now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  for an algebraic alternative,  note that $i^6 = i^2 \cdot i^4 = -1 \cdot 1 = -1\,$ then:

$$
\begin{align}
0 = x^6 + \omega^6 = x^6 - (i \, \omega)^6 &= \big(x^3 - (i \, \omega)^3\big)\big(x^3 + (i \, \omega)^3\big) \\
 &= (x - i \, \omega)(x^2 + i\, \omega x - \omega^2)(x + i \, \omega)(x^2 - i\, \omega x - \omega^2)
\end{align}
$$

Therefore the equation reduces to two linear and two quadratic equations.